# Error: Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete

Tags: errors, citing, natbib

I know that this is a natbib error but I dont know how to solve it. I did not use the package \usepackage{cite} neither is an } missing.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage, bibtotoc,  liststotoc, headings=normal]{report}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Zeichensatz auswählen, damit etwa auch Umlaute dargestellt werden können
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{5pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\textcolor{myblue}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
\usepackage{pdfpages}%ermöglicht das einfügen von Pdfs 
\usepackage{tocstyle} 
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tabularx}%Tabellenumgebung
\usepackage{graphicx}%Umgebung zum setzen von Grafiken
\usepackage{paralist}%Packet für schlankere Aufaehlungen
\usepackage[a4paper, top=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=30mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %Einrichten ser Seitenränder
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\linespread{1.5}%Zeilenabstand =1,5 cm
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{7, 40, 85}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
wtf is this error?
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\end{document}
```

I dont know where the error is so i am giving you my entire code ;) 
THANKS PEEPZZ

Comment: your example produces a different error to the one you ask about `! Too many }'s.
l.1882       \let\fi\fi}
                        {}%
? `  (it would be helpful if you removed all packages unrelated to the error)

Comment: is there any reason to suppose that natbib and apacite can be loaded together? If I comment out apacite than the document is error free

Comment: Further to the coment from @DavidCarlisle, it's best to load only the packages that you actually *need*, and avoid loading the same package more than once. I can't think of any reason to load both `color` and `xcolor`, or both `url` and `hyperref`.

Comment: actually apacite has a `natbibapa` option to "allow a little compatibility" with `natbib` (see the apacite manual)

Comment: I still get the error, even if I delete apacite

\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

hi
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}